# SQL server UPDATE OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to link two servers (the host is SQL Server 2008 and the destination is ORACLE) so that a table on the oracle server is populated by data held in multiple tables on the SQL server.

I have set up an INSERT OPENQUERY, which works perfectly fine. I also want to setup another query to update those records.

So, my insert query, selects records created in the last 24 hours, and inserts them, no problem. But I am struggling to create an UPDATE OPENQUERY script, that will run every 24 hours to make the relevant changes.

Here is my INSERT

```
INSERT OPENQUERY(ukdev662, 'SELECT DOCKET_NUMBER, 
                        APP_NUMBER,
                        ATT,
                        LIT_H, 
                        REVIEW,
                        COUNTRY,
                        NOTICE, 
                        COUNTRY_CODE,
                        FORMALITY_NAME                  
                        FROM GWDMDV29.LOOKUPS__IPMANAGER')
        SELECT PMasters.DocketNumber + ISNULL(Codes_RelationType.Code, '') + ISNULL(PMasters.FilingNumber, '') + 'PTE'
               ,ISNULL(PMasters.AppNumber, '[null]')
               ,ISNULL(PartyDetails_Att.Party, 'Att not assigned')
               ,0
               ,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20130128')
               ,uktst1633.dbo.Countries.Description
               ,'Preserve'
               ,uktst1633.dbo.Countries.WIPO
               ,ISNULL(PartyDetails_Associate.Party, '[null]')
            FROM uktst1633.dbo.Countries
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.PatentMasters PMasters
                ON ( PMasters.Country = uktst1633.dbo.Countries.CountryID )
            INNER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.Codes Codes_CType
                ON ( PMasters.CType = Codes_CType.CodeID
                     AND Codes_CType.CodeTypeID = 'CSP'
                   )
            INNER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.Codes Codes_RelationType
                ON ( Codes_RelationType.CodeID = PMasters.RelationType
                     AND Codes_RelationType.CodeTypeID = 'RLP'
                   )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.Parties Parties_Att
                ON ( Parties_Att.PartyID = PMasters.Att
                     AND ( Parties_Att.PartyTypeID = 'ATP'
                           OR Parties_Att.PartyTypeID IS NULL
                         )
                   )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.PartyDetails PartyDetails_Att
                ON ( PartyDetails_Att.PartyDetailID = Parties_Att.PartyDetailID )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.Parties Parties_Associate
                ON ( Parties_Associate.PartyID = PMasters.Associate
                     AND ( Parties_Associate.PartyTypeID = 'AGP'
                           OR Parties_Associate.PartyTypeID IS NULL
                         )
                   )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN uktst1633.dbo.PartyDetails PartyDetails_Associate
                ON ( PartyDetails_Associate.PartyDetailID = Parties_Associate.PartyDetailID )
            WHERE ( ( Codes_RelationType.Description = 'CONTINUATION'
                      OR Codes_RelationType.Description = 'DIVISION'
                    )
                    AND Codes_CType.Description = 'Regular'
                    AND PMasters.CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
                  )
```

Thanks for any help . I have searched around and cannot find much on OPENQUERY, it all seems to be pretty basic stuff. I tried following this syntax's examples but it got me nowhere...

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
    Table.col2 = other_table.col2
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN
    other_table
ON
    Table.id = other_table.id
```

Comment: did you look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx? If you are using `INSERT OPENQUERY` why are you trying to use `UPDATE TABLE` instead of `UPDATED OPENQUERY`? Also I don't trust query that includes both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` Joins. Pick one and stick to it. Also you don't need all the extra parenthesis for wrapping entire join condition.

Comment: Yes but didn't find it much help as it is just setting a hard-coded value, rather than a value from another field. Thanks for the other feedback on L & R joins